# ERROR: invalid string enlargement request size 1073741823 (redshift Query error)

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I use datagrip as client to connect redshift and encounter a stranger issue which exhaust my whole day.

When I run my query sql the datagrip complains

> [XX000] ERROR: invalid string enlargement request size 1073741823

It seemed that there dont exist a place that I can check more detail error log. And I google this error it also have very little similar question and it seemed maybe due to my field is too long which exceed the max length that redshift can accept. But actually, the story is not such for me I dont have long field, then I comment all my sql statement and re-add them incrementally to locate this issue statement.

Finally, I find the error-msg-triggered statement as below:

```
          (
           case when trunc(request_date_skip_weekend_tmp) = to_date('2022-03-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')                       
           then dateadd(day, 1, trunc(request_date_skip_weekend_tmp))  
           else request_date_skip_weekend_tmp end
          )                                     
        request_date_skip_weekend,
```

After I change it with:

```
            dateadd(day, 1, trunc(request_date_skip_weekend_tmp))  request_date_skip_weekend,
```

the error complain disappear, it is very hard for me to accept the relationship error message and the sql change, I dont know why my the former statement will trigger error complain.

I will appreciate if you can spot why the former expression error or share some knowledge about where can I fetch more detail error message to know what happened.

Comment: More information is needed.  What data type is request_date_skip_weekend_tmp?  Is this calculation the top level of the query or is this used by another select?  Is this result used elsewhere in the same query level?    Does this error occur with all (any) rows of input or is there a specific row that create the error?  What is the value in this row?  FYI  to_date() returns a date but trunc(timestamp) and dateadd() return a timestamp.

Comment: @BillWeiner thanks Bill
1. request_date_skip_weekend_tmp is timestamp
2. this is inner query and used by another select
3. the result will be used in same query level
4. seemed not a special row that create this error, all rows of input will encounter it

I also want to paste this sql but it is too long to provide in question description.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is dates and timestamps but the error is for strings.  So it is likely you have identified a "trigger" and not root cause.  Also since you report that the SQL is very long you could be dealing with compiler optimization changes, moving the failure.  Removing a CASE can cause the compiler/optimizer to choose different structures for the query.

One experiment to try is to change the to_date() to a cast to timestamp so there are no implicit casts ('2022-03-21'::timestamp).  This is unlikely the cause but it may help.

I expect you will need to post the query to get more help.  How large is it?  This error could be related to building a large string in the query OR could be related to the text of the query OR creating the output.  This isn't a standard "string too long" message so this is something more implicit.  You could post to a google doc or some other file sharing service.  Just link in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I agree with you that the statement is just trigger not root cause. And the sql about 200 line, I have put it in google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qc0qvB3QZaCBr23GG5X4J21MTqwvLtpvbY2H2QdFfqw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've gone over the SQL and there doesn't appear to be any text work to speak of and the query itself isn't really that long.  This leads me to think that the issue is in packaging up the results for return.  A way to test this would be to use this as the query in a "CREATE TEMP TABLE AS" statement.  Even if this fails it should provide a different error message (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks Bill, unfortunately I follow your advice use `CREATE TEMP TABLE AS` but encounter same error .

Comment: So same error message?  An explain plan might help find the problem area but I expect some narrowing down of the query might be needed.  Start with the last returned value in the top select and comment it out.  See if the error still happens.  If so move up one value and repeat.  Paring down to the minimum query that shows the error will really help.

Comment: I have try to remove some sql and narrow down the issue, now I have update the google docs.

Comment: I took a look but it wasn't clear which parts were removed and which parts are key to the issue.

Comment: I remove some similar sql logic with current remain sql. And about which parts is key to the issue, this is very strange because I try to remove the color yellow/red sql, both can make the error disappear.  But the sql self seemed no bug.

Comment: So my best guess on what is going on is that you are hitting some limit in an expression.  I haven't found any published limit so this is just a guess.  The lateral alias references you are using forms a "tree" of columns that references 2 other aliases which reference 2 others etc.  These lateral references are just just a code writing convenience and the query compiler flattens them.  So the expression that is being used for dpcn is very large.  I suspect that it is the size of the flattened expression for this that is going over said limit.

Comment: If I'm correct then shifting to DECODE() instead of CASE would solve the issue since this expression is (usually) more compact.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DECODE_expression.html